# Bigcommerce quick view is fuzzy

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a store developed with Bigcommerce stencil, I found that the quick view of the product looks like fuzzy. Why is it fuzzy? Can someone help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "fuzzy"? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I mean pictures and text looks a little fuzzy in quick view.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful and whether or not it is affecting other images or text. It could be a browser issue. Have you tested others?

Comment: Fuzzy like  https://yt3.ggpht.com/-470O-sRIE5M/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/6SVeJ7Tp5R4/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg ? Lol jk, it could be that the quick view is loading the thumbnail version of the images, and they become fuzzy/'distorted' by being stretched. I saw this happen one time as a bug from BC, but that was a while back. Try loading the image source directly to see what it looks like.